# Touch id default alert partially hides keyboard from the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uikeyboard, touch-id

While authenticating user with touch id, The pop-up will appear in the window, but keyboard view has partially disappeared (the accessory view does not dismiss with keyboard) from the window. I have added a screenshot for your reference

[image]

Actually, we expected the result like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSEl4.jpg)

[image]

I called below code to authenticate the user from viewDidLoad function. If we click a text field before the authentication state. The problem will occur.

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";

NSError *error = nil;
if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {

    // If pass coed set means this loop
    [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@“Login With your Touch ID” reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

      if (error) {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // show error message
       });

      return;
      }

     if (success) {
       // allow user to a/c section
     } else {
      // Will add wrong user message
     }

   }];
```

Please help us to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code snippet

Comment: @MaulikBhuptani - Now, I've added the sample code above for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this , you should use `[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:false];` in `viewDidLoad` and in touch id access block again

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
                });`

You also need to monitor whether device supports touch id access or not

Comment: Okay, Thank you :)